# WooCommerce My Account Addresses label not displayed in the website language

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

The "Addresses" tab in "My Account" page is not displayed in the website language when I use Arabic while it should be already translated.

It`s placeholder "the empty highlighted space in the screenshot" still works and navigates to the correct page as expected.

I`m using latest WordPress 5.5 and WooCommerce 4.4.1 and it works normally if I switched to English and worked before in Arabic AFAIK.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J5cu.jpg

for testing purposes, I used TranslatePress plugin to insert the Arabic translation for the string and it worked only while using the plugin.

I also tried debugging using the developer console and playing around with the below codes to no avail, the issue even exists when using the default theme.

1- code responsible for displaying the label of the menu: wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\myaccount\navigation.php

```
    <nav class="woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_menu_items() as $endpoint => $label ) : ?>
            <li class="<?php echo wc_get_account_menu_item_classes( $endpoint ); ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( $endpoint ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $label ); ?></a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_account_navigation' ); ?>
```

2- code for the item displayed which if I changed "Addresses" to something else it appears: wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-account-functions.php

```
        $items = array(
        'dashboard'       => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
        'orders'          => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
        'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-address'    => _n( 'Addresses', 'Address', (int) wc_shipping_enabled(), 'woocommerce' ),
        'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment methods', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-account'    => __( 'Account details', 'woocommerce' ),
        'customer-logout' => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
```

3- translated strings: wp-content\languages\plugins\woocommerce-ar.po

```
#: includes/class-wc-query.php:126
#: includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-advanced.php:284
#: includes/wc-account-functions.php:102
msgid "Addresses"
msgid_plural "Address"
msgstr[0] "العناوين"
msgstr[1] ""
msgstr[2] ""
msgstr[3] ""
msgstr[4] ""
msgstr[5] ""
```

Comment: just did a test on a fresh installation of WP and WC in default language English then switched to Arabic, updated translations and the issue is present

Comment: submitted a github issue @ https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/27428

Answer (score 2):

fixed the issue using Loco Translate, by updating the Arabic translation PO and MO files as per the github issue feedback and woocommerce support forum on the plugins directory.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/27428
and
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updating-translations-after-updates/

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to use javascript code

```
let addressLink=document.querySelector('.woocommerce-MyAccount-navigation-link--edit-address a')
if (addressLink!=null) {
if(addressLink.innerText==""){
    addressLink.innerText="العنوان"
}}
```